# Problems with proof that $p|2^m-2^n$ if $p-1|m-n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

This was a homework assignment that I have already made unsuccesfully. However, no answers were given and I'm still curious. The question is as follows:

"If $p$ is an odd prime number and $m > n$ are two natural numbers such that $m-n$ is divisible by $p-1$, show that $2^m-2^n$ is divisible by $p$."

A hint was given that Fermat's little theorem ($a^p \equiv a \pmod{p}$) should have been used. It looks like a really easy proof, but I couldn't seem to properly construct it. I was a bit distracted by the power of two, but my guess was that you apply the theorem twice such that $a=2$ and $p\in\{m,n\}$, but of course $m$ and $n$ don't have to be prime.

Could anyone please push me in the right direction?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$m-n$ divisible by $p-1$ means that $m-n = (p-1)k$ for some $k$. But then,

$2^{(p-1)k} \pmod p= (2^{(p-1)})^k \pmod p= 1^k \pmod p = 1 \pmod p$

but

$2^{(p-1)k} \pmod p= 2^{m-n} \pmod p= 2^m2^{-n}\pmod p$

and,

$2^m2^{-n} = 1 \pmod p \Rightarrow 2^m = 2^n \pmod p \Rightarrow 2^m - 2^n = 0\pmod p$

Hence the thesis

Note that everything works because 2 is coprime with p

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that $2^m-2^n=2^{n}(2^{m-n}-1)$. And now little Fermat will finish things.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ \ \  m\,\equiv\, n\:\ (mod\ p\!-\!1)\ \Rightarrow\ a^m\equiv a^n\:\ (mod\ p)\,\ \ when\,\ \ p\nmid a$

**Proof** $\rm\,\ m\, =\, n\, +\, k\ (p - 1)\:\Rightarrow\:a^m\equiv\, a^{n+k(p-1)}\!\equiv\, a^n (a^{p-1})^k\!\equiv\, a^n\, 1^k\equiv\, a^n\ $ by little Fermat